# How do I update my Bios on an Intel S5500BC motherboard?

Tags: flash, intel, bios, hardware

So i've just received an Intel S5500BC motherboard in an Intel chassis. I'm not sure how to upgrade the BIOS in it. First of all I have Windows 2008 R2 (SP1) installed. So I thought I might try downloading the Intel update program

> > S5500_WIndows_4_2

I then extracted that and ran `Windows_OFU970_B17\OFU\Setup_Win.exe` .. which copied a bunch of files to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Flashupdt`.

Now, in the command line, when I try to run `Flashupdt.exe` .. it's asking for a flash/bios (config?) file. er.........................................

this is where I'm stuck. What file is this? and where do i grab it from?

Clarrification (for the person who voted to close)
 - This mother board is a *SERVER* motherboard

Comment: Did you read the instructions on the Intel page from which you downloaded the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out :)

I could use EFI to upgrade but I had windows already installed, so I [follow the instructions here](http://communities.intel.com/message/119393#119393) about how to upgrade.

Bascially,

- [Download windows bios upgrading software](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18317&ProdId=3076&lang=eng)
- [Download firmware](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=19692) (this was the file I couldn't find)
- Run the bios flash application and give it the folder name, where the firmware exists.

  `flashupdt -u  <package folder name>`

GLHF!

Answer (score 0):

According to the short look I just took, this mainboard doesn't have a BIOS. It's using the more modern EFI instead.

Find infos, including a demo for the update, [here](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/highlights/server/s5500bc).